# Huge loss value to NaN on regularization and dropout in a deep neural network

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, nan

I'm taking the Deep Learning course on Udacity. One of the tasks that is given is to implement regularization and dropout into a multi layer neural network.

After implementation, my minibatch loss in insanely high at step 0, changes to infinity at step 1, and then becomes non existent for the rest of the output

```
Offset at step 0: 0
Minibatch loss at step 0: 187359330304.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 10.2%
Validation accuracy: 10.0% 

Offset at step 1: 128
Minibatch loss at step 1: inf
Minibatch accuracy: 14.1%
Validation accuracy: 10.0% 

Offset at step 2: 256
Minibatch loss at step 2: nan
Minibatch accuracy: 7.8%
Validation accuracy: 10.0% 

Offset at step 3: 384
Minibatch loss at step 3: nan
Minibatch accuracy: 11.7%
Validation accuracy: 10.0%
```

Here is all the relevant code. I'm confident it has nothing to do with the way I've done my optimization (since that is taken from the given task) or my 
regularization so I'm not sure where else it could be. I've also played around with the number of nodes in the hidden layers (1024 > 300 > 60) but it does the same thing.

Here is my code (excuse the indentation, it's correct in my code):

```
batch_size = 128
num_nodes_1 = 768
num_nodes_2 = 1024
num_nodes_3 = 512
dropout_value = 0.5
beta = 0.01

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

tf_train_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size*image_size))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
tf_valid_data = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
tf_test_data = tf.constant(test_dataset)

def gen_weights_biases(input_size, output_size):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_size, output_size]))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]))
    return weights, biases

weights_1, biases_1 = gen_weights_biases(image_size*image_size, num_nodes_1)
weights_2, biases_2 = gen_weights_biases(num_nodes_1, num_nodes_2)
weights_3, biases_3 = gen_weights_biases(num_nodes_2, num_nodes_3)
weights_4, biases_4 = gen_weights_biases(num_nodes_3, num_labels)

logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_train_data, weights_1) + biases_1
h_layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(logits_1)
h_layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(h_layer_1, dropout_value)

logits_2 = tf.matmul(h_layer_1, weights_2) + biases_2
h_layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(logits_2)
h_layer_2 = tf.nn.dropout(h_layer_2, dropout_value)

logits_3 = tf.matmul(h_layer_2, weights_3) + biases_3
h_layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(logits_3)
h_layer_3 = tf.nn.dropout(h_layer_3, dropout_value)

logits_4 = tf.matmul(h_layer_3, weights_4) + biases_4

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits_4))
regularization = tf.nn.l2_loss(logits_1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(logits_2) + tf.nn.l2_loss(logits_3) + tf.nn.l2_loss(logits_4)
reg_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss + regularization * beta)

global_step = tf.Variable(0)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.5, global_step, 750, 0.8)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(reg_loss, global_step=global_step)

train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits_4)

def make_prediction(input_data):
    p_logits_1 = tf.matmul(input_data, weights_1) + biases_1
    p_layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(p_logits_1)
    p_logits_2 = tf.matmul(p_layer_1, weights_2) + biases_2
    p_layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(p_logits_2)
    p_logits_3 = tf.matmul(p_layer_2, weights_3) + biases_3
    p_layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(p_logits_3)

    p_logits_4 = tf.matmul(p_layer_3, weights_4) + biases_4
    return tf.nn.relu(p_logits_4)

valid_prediction = make_prediction(tf_valid_data)
test_prediction = make_prediction(tf_test_data)

num_steps = 10001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print("Initialized \n")

for step in range(num_steps):
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]

    feed_dict = {tf_train_data:batch_data, tf_train_labels:batch_labels}

    _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, reg_loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if(step % 1 == 0):
        print("Offset at step %d: %d" % (step, offset))
        print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
        print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
        print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%% \n" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))

print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the standard deviation for the weights. I'm not sure why this sorted it out and if someone could explain I'd appreciate it. Anyway the fix was:

```
def gen_weights_biases(input_size, output_size):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_size, output_size], stddev=math.sqrt(2.0/(input_size))))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]))
    return weights, biases
```

The beta rate also had to be lowered to 0.0001

Comment: Weight initalization is very important for good convergene. The initialization you have used now is from https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852 where you can read more about it.

Comment: True. Badly initialized neural network is very likely to explode. I'm going to add one more paper on init and why it's important: https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422